# How to write a JS inline of HTML input?

Tags: javascript

I have a browser check:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.browser.chrome) {
  //show document write input only if chrome = true else, ignore it
}
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input name="name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" **IF CHROME == TRUE? document.write("style="position:relative; margin-top:-3px; margin-left:-1px;"");** >
```

Obviously the above is incorrect .. Can someone please explain the proper way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with browser-sniffing? What is that Chrome does wrong (or differently)?

Comment: Its working fine. I just want to know how to make javascript write to the HTML based on a IF check.. I just used the above as an example.

Comment: Well, in Chromium 18 (Ubuntu 11.04) `$.browser.safari` reports `true`; so I don't think that you can test for Chrome, just `safari` or `webkit`.

Comment: No i tested fine - I used alert() successfully. The check works.. I just want to basically have a variable -- like $say = 'something'l the variable is inline with my HTML and basically if the JS returns TRUE i want my variable to echo into the page else -- ignore it..  make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not a fan of this one-off hack, the following explains how it can be obtained given that `$.browser.chrome` evaluates as expected.

---

The document cannot be *written to* inline at this point, however, the attributes of the element can be changed. For instance, inside the conditional if-check:

```
$(inputSelector).attr('style',
    'position:relative; margin-top:-3px; margin-left:-1px;');
```

However, since the `style` attribute, which is "text", is synthesized to a "stye object", it is usually best to avoid text-DOM access. This can be achieved using the `jQuery.css` method:

```
$(inputSelector).css({
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: '-3px',
    marginLeft: '-1px'
})
```

Where `inputSelector` is an appropriate selector to match the appropriate element(s). For instance, `<input name="theName" ..` can be matched with `[name="theName"]`. See [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details.

Comment: so if i give the input an id of `#name` i can say inside of my IF: `$(#name).attr('"style=', 'position:blah;"')` is this correct?

Comment: If you give it an *id* you can use `#id`. For the `name` attribute you can use `[name="theNameOfTheInput"]`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/